# how to match groups of strings that don't contain some substring

Tags: php, javascript, regex, pcre

I have to match groups of strings that have as bounds the "__" char sequence (two underscores)

for instance:

```
hello __1the_re__ my name is __pe er33__
```

"1the_re" and "pe er33" should be matched

my problem is defining "a string that doesn't contain a sequence of characters"

```
/__((?!__).*)__/
```

Ive tried this, but it is not working...

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close:

```
/__((?!__).)*__/
```

works. The star must be outside the repeated group so the lookahead is performed at every position, not just right after the leading `__`.

Since this doesn't capture the right text (I'm guessing that you want the content between the double underscores to be captured), you probably want

```
/__((?:(?!__).)*)__/
```

Comment: nice! ok now i understand what was wrong with my regex, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your grouping, you want to match one of the following:

1. Any character followed by any character not `_`.
2. Any character not `_`

Regex:

```
  /__(.[^_]|[^_])*__/
```

As the first matches first, it goes on. For nicer match extraction, add the non-capturing flag and match the inner:

```
 /__((?:.[^_]|[^_])*)__/
```

Example:

```
$subject = 'hello __1the_re__ my name is __pe er33__';
$pattern = '/__((?:.[^_]|[^_])*)__/';
$r = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1the_re
    [1] => pe er33
)
```

But obviously it's just much easier to make the quantifier lazy:

```
/__(.+?)__/
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use non-greedy mark: "?".

```
/__((?!__).*?)__/g
// javascript:
>>> "hello __1the_re__ my name is __pe er33__".match(/__((?!__).*?)__/g)
["__1the_re__", "__pe er33__"]
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense - if you make the quantifier lazy, you don't need the lookahead assertion.